# Git equivalent of hg purge

Tags: git, mercurial

Not just the command, but the actual behavior... hg purge will delete all untracked files.

I thought it was git clean, but nope...

```
$ git clean
fatal: clean.requireForce defaults to true and neither -n nor -f given; refusing to clean

$ git clean -n
Would not remove src/

$ git clean -f
Not removing src/
```

So, it feels like git just told me to go f*** myself, lol... I'm not asking this thing if it agrees, I just want Git to do what I ask of it.

How do I convince Mr. Git to please do me the favor of removing my untracked files?

Comment: I think the correct express is to `fsck` yourself :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you want to also remove directories, run `git clean -f -d`

If you just want to remove ignored files, run `git clean -f -X`

If you want to remove ignored as well as non-ignored files, run `git clean -f -x`

Note the case difference on the X for the two latter commands.

EDIT: useful [linkie](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html) bout this git operation :)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a quick translation:

- `hg purge` translates to `git clean -f -d` (deletes only untracked files and directories)
- `hg purge --all` translates to `git clean -f -d -x` (also deleted ignored files)

Git also has `git clean -f -X` (upper case X) which only deletes ignored files but leaves untracked files untouched. Mercurial has no equivalent for this.